# Getting exact data from Google Trends

Tags: google-trends

I am searching on Google Trends who has searched on a particular topic (say 100 searches per month) , How can i extract data who are those people who have searched that particular topic, can i have their details or any thing using API?

thanks

I have tried to search online but not able to get the desired data

Answer (score 0):

Google Trends data is aggregated and anonymized, so the information you're looking for is not available.

From [Google Trends Help Center](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365533?hl=en&ref_topic=6248052):

> After search data is collected, we categorize it, connect it to a
>   topic, and remove any personal information.